# linux, X11, dialog menu with items

Tags: linux, script, xorg, dialog

I'm looking for a scriptable dialog utility for Linux/X11/Wayland that I'd run like this:

```
$ ask F="Delete all files" D="Launch drones" X="Open images"
```

and it'd display X11 dialog window similar to this:

```
(F) Delete all files
(D) Launch drones
(X) Open images
```

that would disappear either after pressing `Escape` or after pressing any letter specified (`F`, `D`, `X`). In the first case it'd output nothing and exit with code 1, in the second case it'd output line with the pressed letter and exit with code 0.

I know 9menu or ratmenu. I know I could make one but I hate to mess with available GUI toolkits.

Comment: Several possibilities for that in Unix/Linux. Have a look at Zenity, kdialog, gtkdialog; each is a scriptable command line program for displaying X dialogs with widgets galore. The problem is deciding from all the options of each.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Tcl/Tk ( www.tcl.tk ).  Tcl is a scripting-language, and the Tk-extension to it lets you make GUIs pretty easily.  There are online examples, and it's also mentioned in books like "Running Linux".

(With Tcl you can also get `expect`, an extension that lets you create scripts that interacts with other programs, and contains challenge-response pairs... eg. the script starts `ftp`, and when it receives "ogin" and "assword", it responds with your username and password.)

You'll probably find `tcl`, `tk` and `expect` in the repository for your linux-distro.